# report qweb not displayed

Tags: python, xml, odoo

im new in reporting qweb, i want to practice it, then i try to creat a report for my module gestion_des_etudiants, i know something is missing in my code, i need your help  :

report_etudiant.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Custom report.-->
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="report_etudiant_document">
            <t t-call="report.external_layout">
                <div class="page">
                <div class="row">
                    <h3>Teeeeeeeeeeeeest</h3>

                </div>
                </div>
            </t>
        </template>
        <template id="report_etudiant">
            <t t-call="report.html_container">
            <t t-foreach="doc_ids" t-as="doc_id">

               <h3>Tiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiitle</h3>

        </t>
    </t>
</template>


    </data>
</openerp>
```

etudiant_report.xml :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <report
            id="action_report_etudiant"
            string="Attestation de scolarité"
            model="etudiant"
            report_type="qweb-pdf"
            name="gestion_des_etudiants.report_etudiant"
            file="gestion_des_etudiants.report_etudiant"
        />
    </data>
</openerp>
```

And when i print the report, i get an empty pdf file, no errors but empty, not even header or footer

Comment: Can you please update the code with .py code to render the template.?
Or try both of these codes in a single file combined..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  you said, the report is generating but you can't see any pages.
here, you have defind two templates.

To get the pages in a qweb-pdf, we must use these tags

```
<div class="page">
<div class="row">
```

In your code, you have defined two templates, in template-1 you have used

```
<div class="page">
<div class="row">
```

In template-2, you have not included the above two tags, and you configured the report action for the template-2

```
<report 
 id="action_report_etudiant" 
 string="Attestation de scolarité" 
 model="etudiant" 
 report_type="qweb-pdf" 
 name="gestion_des_etudiants.report_etudiant" 
 file="gestion_des_etudiants.report_etudiant" />
```

That's the reason its not printing.

So,either include the above div tags in template-2, or configure report action for template-1

Comment: thanks a lot, it's working now, i configured the report for the template-1 and it worked :

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling your **report_etudiant_document** template to show what you need, so inside your `t-foreach` you need to add this line:

**Edit:**

`<t t-raw="translate_doc(doc_id, doc_model, 'gestion_des_etudiants.report_etudiant_document')"/>`

I hope this can help you!

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, i did what you said, but now i get a new error :

QWebException: ""'etudiant' object has no attribute 'partner_id'" while evaluating
'doc.partner_id.lang'" while evaluating

Comment: Sorry It's because you are not using it in your report, my bad...I copied this line from my own report, just remove it! I'm going to edit my answer

Comment: i thnil we have to change partner_id to something else, because after editing the ligne like you do, i get a this error : QWebException: "translate_doc() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)" while evaluating
"translate_doc(doc_id, doc_model, 'gestion_des_etudiants.report_etudiant_document')"

Comment: @JuanSalcedo  your try to give your answer is totally wrong                    <t t-raw="translate_doc(doc_id, doc_model, 'gestion_des_etudiants.report_etudiant_document')"/> this function which you are mentioned that it is not the actual problem but it is the use for transalate this report into another language at that time this function will be used in Qweb

Answer (score 1):

You can refer our blog on [Qweb Report](http://blog.emiprotechnologies.com/create-qweb-report-odoo/).

There we have describe everything in details.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Custom report.-->
<openerp>
    <data>
       <report
        id="action_report_etudiant"
        string="Attestation de scolarité"
        model="etudiant"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        name="gestion_des_etudiants.report_etudiant"
        file="gestion_des_etudiants.report_etudiant" />

        <template id="report_etudiant">
          <t t-call="report.external_layout">
          <t t-call="report.html_container">
          <div class="page">
             <t t-foreach="doc_ids" t-as="doc_id">
               <h3>Tiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiitle</h3>
             </t>
          </div>
         </t>
        </t>
      </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```